# JavaFX MediaPlayer: Changing Speed with setRate Lags Video

Tags: java, video, javafx, media-player, frame-rate

I made a basic GUI via JavaFX that runs a video stored on a local computer - I did this through MediaView. On that GUI, I added a slider bar below that video, and any changes to the slider bar will result in the video going faster or slower (i.e. the slider bar can make the video go from .5 speed to 1.5 speed).

The problem is that, whenever the user moves the slider and changes the speed of the video, the video lags. I programmed the slider so that, if the video speed is changed by 1/100th, it will update the speed/rate via the setRate method. (For example, if you move the slider from 1.00 to 1.01, the speed will update, but it won't update if you move it from 1.001 to 1.002). Because the user is going to be updating the speed of the video quite a bit, I can't have it lag each time the speed is changed. How do I stop this lag?

Here's my code for the start method:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void start(Stage stage) {
    initializeMediaPlayer(); 
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    mediaView.setFitWidth(400);
    Slider speedSlider = initializeSlider();

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(mediaView);
    borderPane.setBottom(speedSlider);

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
}
```

My code for initializeMediaPlayer:

```
private void initializeMediaPlayer(){
    Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("Test.mp4").toString());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
}
```

My code for initializeSlider:

```
private Slider initializeSlider(){
    Slider speedSlider = new Slider(.5, 1.5, 1); //(min,max,current_value)
    HBox.setHgrow(speedSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
    speedSlider.setMaxWidth(800);
    speedSlider.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    speedSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new SliderListener(speedSlider));
    return speedSlider;
}
```

And finally, my code for speedSlider, or the slider event listener; it's embedded within the main class, meaning it has access to the mediaPlayer global variable.

```
private class SliderListener implements InvalidationListener{
    private Slider speedSlider;
    private double lastSpeed = 1.0;

    public SliderListener(Slider SS){
        speedSlider = SS;
    }

    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {    
        if (speedSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        double currentSpeed = Math.round( (int) (speedSlider.getValue() * 100) )/100.0; 
            if(currentSpeed != lastSpeed){
                lastSpeed = currentSpeed;
                mediaPlayer.setRate(currentSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do I stop this lag? Once again, the video only lags whenever the rate is changed via setRate. I tried allocating more RAM to the program, and I tried updating the speed in the Platform.runLater command, but both options did nearly nothing to prevent the lag.

Comment: With the code above I can't see any 'noticeable' lag while changing the slider value, maybe it has to do about the computers process power? Anyway I would recommend doing like ther other media players doing it, for example by Pressing "+ , -" or having two buttons and a label to increase and decrease the speed + to show the speed rate. Then you will reduce the total changes on speed and reduce your lag.

Comment: You're right: this had to do with my computer's processing power. When I ran this program on another computer, the lag virtually went away. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime environment was the problem: as soon as I launched this program on another computer, the lag disappeared.